# Directly compress stdout

Tags: command-line, tar, stdout

can someone tell me if is possible to directly compress stdout?

I would like to do this in one step without creating temporary file files.txt...

Example:

```
cat file* > files.txt
tar -czf files.tar files.txt
rm files.txt
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Just to confirm - you're trying to create a tarball containing a single file, right?

Comment: This is correct. I just need to tar "files.txt" and noting else.

Comment: Not trying to be critical, just wondering about your methodology here: Is there a reason you're trying to create a tar file containing just the one file?

Comment: I do this because this files.txt is huge (100 MB+) and I need to transfer it from server A to server B. (compressed file is 90% smaller)

Comment: Note that just tar-ing the file does *not* provide compression. It's just a method of packaging many files up into one file.

Comment: (the compression is provided externally, by gzip, as you're specifying the `z` argument to tar)

Comment: Al this is correct, but the question is still the same...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bypass the `tar` part of `.tar.gz` in this case, since you don't need to handle multiple files, and skip straight to `gzip` for compression.

To compress

```
gzip < file > file.gz
```

To decompress

```
gzip -d file.gz
```

or equivalently

```
gunzip file.gz
```

You can also use the `bzip2` and `xz` compression utilities with similar syntax. `xz` usually produces smaller compressed files than either `gzip` or `bzip2`.

(Footnote)

If you are creating a compressed file and then using `scp` to transfer it, you can use built-in compression:

```
cat file | ssh -C user@remote 'cat >> remote_file'
```

or

```
scp -C file user@remote:/path/on/remote
```

or

```
rsync -avz file user@remote:/path/on/remote
```

Comment: I need to create a .gz file from stdout, I would like to skip my cat and rm step (see example)... can this be done?

Comment: Wolfy: when using the commands from this answer, you don't need the `cat` or `rm` steps. It's a single command to compress the file.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the f option off.

Something I've done is like this:

```
tar -cz *.xml
```

This prints to stdout.  I could then use some code to ssh into the server tar/gzip them all up and save locally without needing to create a new file on the server.